# RegionPlot3D ColorFunction Not Centered

Tags: plotting, color, regions

`RegionPlot` (and `RegionPlot3D`) appears to use the lower right corner of the plot as the origin for the coordinates fed to `ColorFunction`. Below I create a disk centered at the origin and impose what I would have expected to be a circularly symmetric color function. (I use `DiscretizeRegion` here so the color function is sampled at more points and looks much better, but the issue is visible without it)

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]], ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue@(Sqrt[(x)^2 + (y)^2])]]
```

If I manually center the shape I get the expected result.

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Hue@(Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2])]]
```

Is there some nice way to fix this? Some way to tell `RegionPlot` where I want the color origin to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

"12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"
```

From the documentation for [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), "With the usual default setting ColorFunctionScaling -> True, all arguments supplied to func are scaled to lie in the range 0 to 1." You need to use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` when you don't want the `ColorFunction` using rescaled values.

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue@Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

The actual range of your `Sqrt[x^2+y^2]` is

```
{min, max} = #[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= y <= 1}, {x, 
     y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {0, Sqrt[2]} *)
```

Scaling accordingly,

```
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue@Rescale[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {min, max}]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh man, that's whack. I read the documentation on ColorFunctionScaling and I'm pretty sure I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The "dumb" way to fix this is to just use `BoundingRegion` to rescale the the coordinates provided to the `ColorFunction` eg:

```
ClearAll[rescale, reg]
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]];
rescalefn[region_] := Evaluate[{#1, #2} + First[BoundingRegion[region]]/2] &
RegionPlot[reg, 
 ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y}, Hue[Sqrt[(x)^2 + (y)^2]]] @@ 
     rescalefn[reg][##] &)]
```

Returns the expected plot. This only works if the origin of your region is at the center of the `BoundingRegion` though, but it shouldn't be too difficult to modify this to work for other origins.